# Facebook like button disappear and wont display again

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I had facebook like button on my page http://www.puzzlekosice.sk/
and one day it disappeared.

I tried to refresh the code but no luck, I don't know what could be wrong. There is an empty area on right side.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

use the [lint](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) tool to re-scrape it.  Here is a great post about why: http://www.allwebmaster.com/fix-facebook-like-button-not-working/